# command substitution breaks yarn script on windows

Tags: reactjs, windows, powershell, yarnpkg

I am trying to get a web-project to run cross-platform, however I ran into the following problem. I don't think the project details matter, so I will just post the problematic lines from the package.json here:

```
"dev-local": "cross-env PREFIX=$(whoami) yarn dev"
```

The problem arises when used on Windows. The execution fails with

```
yarn was unexpected at this time.
```

If I use hardcoded values it works fine, but that is of course not a viable solution

```
"dev-local": "cross-env PREFIX=hello yarn dev"
```

So it looks like the problem is the command substitution - however I don't understand why. I am using windows powershell.

Comment: when I do that, it looks like the content of PREFIX is $(whoami), so it passes it as a string instead of actually getting the username

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find an answer, but this can be used as a workaround if anyone runs into a similar problem:

```
"dev-local": "cross-env PREFIX=$(whoami) yarn dev",
"dev-local-windows": "set PREFIX=%USERNAME%& yarn dev",
```